# How to escape \" as absolute, concrete, unique, single value? Java

Tags: java, escaping, replaceall

I'm trying to replace \" backslash and quote to ", those characters are together in my text, so I do a replace but the compiler it say that my escaping syntax is incorrect:

```
String myText = "Animal:{\"name\":\"turkey\"}";
```

As you can observe here there is \" together so I'm want to replace by just one quote "
To look like this:

```
"Animal:{"name":"turkey"}"
```

So my replace its looks like:

```
myText.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
```

- To escape a backslash we need \\
- To escape a quote we need \"

With that logic I have this `\\\"` but its not working, its incorrect for the compiler...
I already tried:

```
myText.replaceAll("\\*", "");
```

But this one is not want I want in my string.

Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "its incorrect for the compiler"?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your 1st line of syntax is not Java.  Is that a typo? String myText: "Animal:{\"name\":\"turkey\"}"

Comment: I think the compiler error is that you are breaking up a perfectly good String into a String mixed with 2 variables `"Animal:{"name":"turkey"}"`. See that you all of a sudden introduced the variable _name_ and _turkey_. Maybe share the compiler error, although I suspect it will point to this problem anyway.

Comment: Can you tell us where that String come from? I feel like you're receiving a Json response from an API and you want to escape the quotes manually instead of de-serializing / serializing the message correctly. using a library such as Jackson..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are exposing the problem wrongly.
If you write a `String` like this in the source code:

```
String myText = "Animal:{\"name\":\"turkey\"}";
```

... the `String` is *already escaped*.
It means you may print :

```
System.out.println(myText);
```

... and you would get in output:

```
Animal:{"name":"turkey"}
```

... without need of doing anything else.

So I can only imagine two things:

1. Your question is: Can I write `String myText = "Animal:{"name":"turkey"}";` without backslashes in the source code? => The answer is no, or the compiler wouldn't know what's the delimiter of the text and what's just another character of the text.
2. Your question is missing information: for example, you are receiving this `String` from a service which is responding in Json, and over the transport this `String` is keeping the backslashes on the quotes.

If that's the case, you should rather use the proper library to parse the message as `JsonNode`. Add a dependency to `jackson-databind` into your project and then use these methods:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // <-- create ObjectMapper
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString); // <-- parse your Json string into a JsonNode
String niceJsonString = actualObj.toPrettyString(); // <-- formats the Json properly
```

If your question falls in my second guess, then I suggest you have a look at [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson), it is a pretty powerful library to work with Json (a market standard for Json messaging in Java).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first argument of replaceAll is not just a String, it is a regex string, and regex also uses backslash to escape the next character.  So you need another entire level of escaping, so that what you are passing to regex is the string you have, i.e. escape backslash escape quote, so that the regex will search for the sequence backslash quote.

```
myText.replaceAll("\\\\\\\"", "\"");
```

I think that's right.